# refactor fat arrow nested rxjs stream

Tags: ecmascript-6, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am playing with http://reactivex.io/learnrx/.  In better effort to learn rxjs.

The array that I am working through is below.  I am just trying to get the id's out of the array.

I am able to get the answer to work but feel that answer could be better written.

```
var movieLists = [
        {
            name: "New Releases",
            videos: [
                {
                    "id": 70111470,
                    "title": "Die Hard",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 654356453,
                    "title": "Bad Boys",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 5.0,
                    "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Dramas",
            videos: [
                {
                    "id": 65432445,
                    "title": "The Chamber",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 675465,
                    "title": "Fracture",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 5.0,
                    "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Here is the answer that I came up with

```
          movieLists
                  .map( movieList => movieList.videos
                  .map(video => video.id)  )   // don't like this part
                  .concatAll()
```

I am basically nesting a map inside of another map then calling concat all.

Is it possible to refactor that second map fat arrow so it can sit outside of the first?

```
.map()
.map()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order of operators.

```
Observable.from(movieLists)
  .map(movie => movie.videos)
  .concatAll()
  .map(movie => movie.id);
```

Comment: I didn't even think about that.  I also found that using flatmap worked but this is better thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `concatAll()` after mapping to movies:

```js
var movieLists = [
    {
        name: "New Releases",
        videos: [
            {
                "id": 70111470,
                "title": "Die Hard",
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg",
                "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 4.0,
                "bookmark": []
            },
            {
                "id": 654356453,
                "title": "Bad Boys",
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys.jpg",
                "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 5.0,
                "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Dramas",
        videos: [
            {
                "id": 65432445,
                "title": "The Chamber",
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber.jpg",
                "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 4.0,
                "bookmark": []
            },
            {
                "id": 675465,
                "title": "Fracture",
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture.jpg",
                "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 5.0,
                "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
            }
        ]
    }
];

Rx.Observable.from(movieLists)
    .map(movieList => movieList.videos)
    .concatAll()
    .map(video => video.id)
    .do(console.log)
    .subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

---

**But**:
Basically you want to flatten the Array and extract the ids - there is no need for RxJS here at all, and using the native methods should be faster as well:

```js
var movieLists = [
    {
        name: "New Releases",
        videos: [
            {
                "id": 70111470,
                "title": "Die Hard",
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg",
                "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 4.0,
                "bookmark": []
            },
            {
                "id": 654356453,
                "title": "Bad Boys",
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys.jpg",
                "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 5.0,
                "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Dramas",
        videos: [
            {
                "id": 65432445,
                "title": "The Chamber",
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber.jpg",
                "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 4.0,
                "bookmark": []
            },
            {
                "id": 675465,
                "title": "Fracture",
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture.jpg",
                "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                "rating": 5.0,
                "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
            }
        ]
    }
];

// Step 1: get all the videos as an multi-dimensional array
const videos = movieLists.map(movie => movie.videos);
// Step 2: flatten the array
const flatVideos = [].concat.apply([], videos);
// Step 3: Map to ids
const videoIds = flatVideos.map(video => video.id);
console.log(videoIds);
```

I've written this in 3 steps, but those can be concatenated just as well.

Comment: I figured out how to do this with flat map   console.log( movieLists
       .map(movieList => movieList.videos)
       .flatMap(videos => videos)
       .map(post => post.id)
       ).

Comment: I agree there is no use for rxjs but my goal is to get comfortable with it.

Comment: okay, great - maybe you want to post your solution and accept it as the answer since it might be interesting for others to see different solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single operator:

```
Observable.from(movieLists)
  .concatMap(
    movie => movie.videos, 
    (_, video) => video.id
  )
```