# Advanced example of rxjs5 flattening

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

I have similar data structure to this:

```
let userInfo =  [
      {
       id: 'id1',
       users: [
       {
        name: 'userName1',
        job: 'userJob',
       },
       {
        name: 'userName2',
        job: 'userJob',
       }
      ]
     },
      {
       id: 'id2',
       users: [
       {
        name: 'userName3',
        job: 'userJob',
       },
       {
         name: 'userName4',
        job: 'userJob',
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
```

Users are 
I expected new flattened user stream with RxJS5:

```
    {
     parent: id,        // parent id, where users[] come from...
     name: 'userName'
     job: 'userJob'
    }
```

What is the clean functional way to archive this? Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach would just use `concatMap()` to merge the internal Observable created with `Rx.Observable.from` with the list of users updated with their parent id.

```
let userInfo =  [
  {
    id: 'id1',
    users: [
      {
        name: 'userName1',
        job: 'userJob',
      },
      {
        name: 'userName2',
        job: 'userJob',
      }
    ]
  },
  {...}
];

let source = Rx.Observable.from(userInfo)
  .concatMap(group => {
    return Rx.Observable.from(group['users'])
      .map(user => {
        user['parent'] = group.id;
        return user;
      });
  });

source.subscribe(
  res => console.log(res)
);
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/miximas/2/edit?js,console

There're a lot of similar question already:

- [refactor fat arrow nested rxjs stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609016/refactor-fat-arrow-nested-rxjs-stream/41609467#41609467)
- [Merge subarrays using Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346728/merge-subarrays-using-observables/40347238#40347238)
- [RxJS: JSON data with an array, processing each item further in the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092488/rxjs-json-data-with-an-array-processing-each-item-further-in-the-stream/41096657#41096657)