# RxJS 5 - websocket array messages

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, rxjs, rxjs5

I receive messages via a websocket connection in this format :

```
    [
      {
        //msg 1
      },
      {
        //msg 2
      },
      ....
    ]
```

based on some examples I found on the web here is my code:

```
public messages: Subject<Message> = new Subject<Message>();
//...
        this.messages = <Subject<Message>>this.wsService
            .connect(COMMUNICATION_URL)
            .map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
                let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
                //data is an array [ {..} , {..}, ...]
                return data;
            });


        this.messages.subscribe(msg => {
            console.log(msg);
            // msg is an array of objects [ {..} , {..}, ...]
            // I want to be just the object
        });
```

What I want to achieve is to split the message (array) in objects and when I subscribe I want to receive those objects and not the array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most easily just use `concatAll()` or `mergeAll()` that when used with arrays in RxJS 5 reemits all its items.

```
this.messages = <Subject<Message>>this.wsService
    .connect(COMMUNICATION_URL)
    .map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        //data is an array [ {..} , {..}, ...]
        return data;
    })
    .concatAll();
```

I didn't test it but I think you could also use shorter variant:

```
this.messages = <Subject<Message>>this.wsService
    .connect(COMMUNICATION_URL)
    .concatMap((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        //data is an array [ {..} , {..}, ...]
        return data;
    })
```

See similar answers:

- [RxJS Refactor nested map statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170157/rxjs-refactor-nested-map-statement/40180701#40180701)
- [Merge subarrays using Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346728/merge-subarrays-using-observables/40347238#40347238)
- [refactor fat arrow nested rxjs stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609016/refactor-fat-arrow-nested-rxjs-stream/41609467#41609467)
- [Subscribing to a nested Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250882/subscribing-to-a-nested-observable/40257871#40257871)

Comment: I've tested the concatMap example and works like a charm. Thanks